# Audio and video no longer working after upgrade from 22.04 to 23.04

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, google-chrome, youtube, 23.04

I have upgraded my Ubuntu 22.04 to 23.04 and neither audio nor video on YouTube is working.

I used https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-22-04-to-ubuntu-23-04 for the upgrade.

When I check the console of Chrome, I get no error messages.

Are there any extra things I need to configure or check to restore audio and video?

I'm running it on VirtualBox 7.0.6 with Additions of the same version.

Comment: After rebooting I know get the error "Oh No! Something has gone wrong." With a Log Out button that does not seem to do anything.

Comment: After the 12th reboot, suddenly it was working again, except for the audio and video

Comment: After reducing the CPUs from 2  to 1 and memory from 6144 to 3072. It seems to work as expected.